# What insect is eating my beet greens?

Tags: insects, leafy-vegetables

Consider:

[image]

What insect could possibly be eating my beet greens? Each one has multiple holes in the leaves. What can I do to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like flea beetle damage. Use floating row covers to avoid it.

Comment: I thought of slugs, at first, but then noticed the many thin areas and smaller holes. There could be some slug damage, of course, but it does look like the majority of the problems are the beetles. Nice call.

Comment: Feel free to mark it "answered" if you think this is the right call!